# how to show pdf,excel files from folder in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I just started learning of AngularJS. I want to show files in a modal popup. I can show image files but now I want to show exl/csv/pdf files in that popup as well.

**view**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="form-group" >
      <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="image in upFiles">
         <img class="img img-thumbnail center-block"  ng-src="{{IMAGE_LOCATION+image}}" />{{image}} 
         //csv/exl/pdf here
      </li>
   </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$scope.viewFile = function(document_id, emp_id) {
    loadData('viewUpload', {
        document_id: document_id,
        emp_id: emp_id
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.upFiles = data;
        //console.log($scope.upFiles);
        $scope.IMAGE_LOCATION = base_url + 'application/assets/uploads/' + emp_id + '/' + document_id + '/';
    });
}
```

**$scope.upFiles** contains filenames only like
eg: ["name1.jpg","name2.jpg","name3.csv"]

Comment: When you say you want to show files do you mean the contents of the file or just the name of the file?

Comment: I think you need to parse the content from the files first. For excel, you can try xlsx or node-xlsx. For csv, you can read it by yourself since it is text.

Comment: content of the file